# 4 wire Samsung Dryer Cord Cross Wired - Dryer not working after corrected

Tags: dryer

Just bought a used Samsung front loading dryer, and the guy we bought it from swapped his long cord out for the original short cord, but apparently had the red wire in the middle and white on the left...when I plugged it in, it sparked and the Elec. Panel Circuit Breakers tripped.

I assumed it might be cross wired, saw a video and moved the red wire to the outside and white wire to the middle, plugged it back in, CB tripped once...reset it, but nothing.  No power to dryer, at least it's not responding and CB doesn't trip anymore.  The dryer was working when we picked it up.  What can we do to get the dryer working, now that the cord is wired correctly?

OK, just had an Appliance Repair guy out to the house...and we sorta lucked out...he said I reattached the cord properly, and the circuit board checks out OK.  It appears the surge killed the power in the line.  So either my Master Panel Dryer Circuit Breakers tripped, permanently, or there is a short in the wall outlet, as he got no power out of the outlet.  My money is on the CB now being inop.  Now we need an Electrician to most likely replace those breakers in the panel, and check the path to the dryer.

Comment: Find the wiring diagram for that exact model, probably online, and make sure it is wired correctly.  Sparks and tripping might have caused damage inside, maybe just a fuse, maybe burned out control board.  Also make sure your house circuit is wired correctly.  Test for voltage.

Comment: Wait, has NEC 110.3(B) been revised to no longer require following the approved manufacturer instructions, and just watch Youtube videos from some random yutz whose sole qualification is playing the Youtube ranking game?

Comment: I think you've successfully blown the "fuse" consisting of all the 120V electronics in the dryer after applying 240V to them. **Always triplecheck wiring before connecting appliances to power.** Or at least do that next time.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how to follow up when you receive answers. We don't mark questions [solved] here.

Comment: Again, please take the [tour]. We're playing edit-pong here.

Answer (score 6):

One possibility is that the previous connection was a 3-wire connection (NEMA 10-30) and you now have a 4-wire connection (NEMA 14-30). If that is the case and the neutral-ground bond in the dryer was not removed then a miswire could easily cause a breaker trip. For example, if one of the hots and neutral are reversed but neutral still connected to ground, then when you plug it in you get hot (receptacle) to neutral (dryer) to ground (dryer) to ground (receptacle) which will cause an immediate trip. There are a bunch of other possibilities as well.

*There is no industry-standard arrangement of wires.* Lookup the manual for your model to find out the correct arrangement. Then double-check the neutral-ground bond. You should be using a 4-wire NEMA 14-30 receptacle and the neutral-ground bond in the dryer should be *removed*.

Also double-check your receptacle configuration. Unplug the dryer. Reset the breaker. (If it won't reset with the dryer unplugged then you have bigger problems.) You should have 240V between the hots, 120V between each hot and neutral, 120V between each hot and ground, 0V between neutral and ground. If any of those readings is wrong, fix that before fixing the dryer.

If you have a 3-wire receptacle, **replace that before proceeding**.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the control electronics inside has been fried.  If they are intended to run on 120V (hot to neutral), but the mis-wire put 240V (hot to hot), then there could be any amount of damage.

You'd need someone expert enough to diagnose the problem and maybe replace the main circuit board.

Answer (score -1):

*Answer was edited into the question*

Electrician checked the outlet, inspected the Breaker Box and noticed the Breakers were still in the Tripped position. He properly shut the breakers off and back on. Problem solved. The Breakers worked, they protected the Dryer, which works just fin again. But so glad I started with the Cord, and found the correct wiring pattern, and corrected it. We are good to go now! Thank you all!

Had some help look at the power issue. Turns out I did not completely reset the panel circuit breaker. Flipped it all the way off and back on, and everything works correctly. So, didn't fry anything, CB did it's job...reset and good to go! Good advice, double check everything, especially wiring and Circuit Breakers! Thank you all!